# Why it looks different in chrome (only on windows) and firefox my style rules?

Tags: php, css, windows, google-chrome, zurb-foundation

I want to create a `div` where an image is on the left side and the text on the right side. I want to create this with `PHP`. It looks like this in Firefox: [image: looks like this in firefox]
but the situation is different in Chrome on Windows: [image: this is how it looks in chrome on Windows] But on Ubuntu appears totally correctly!
I create the HTML with this PHP script:

```
echo'<div class="callout large clearfix card">';
echo'<div class="float-left">';
echo '<img src="img/'.$card['cardimg'].'">';
echo '</div>';  
echo'<div class="float-right carddescription">';
echo '<div class="title">';
echo $card["description"];
echo "</div>";
echo "<br>";
echo '<div class="additionalinfo">';
echo htmlspecialchars_decode($card["additionalinfo"], ENT_QUOTES);
echo '</div>';  
echo "<br>";
echo '<div class="creator">';
echo "creator: ".$card["uploader"];
echo '</div>';  
echo '</div>';  
echo '</div>';
```

And I use foundation CSS with this few rules:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
   .card{
        margin-top: 2%;
        margin-bottom: 2%;
    }

    .card img{
        max-width: 20em;
        height: auto;
    }

    .card .carddescription{
        max-width: 70%;
    }

    .card .title{
        font-size: 2.5em;
        background-color: black;
        color: white;
        padding-left: 5%;
        padding-top: 1%;
        padding-bottom: 1%;
    }

    .card .additionalinfo{
        font-weight: bold;
        padding-top: 1%;
    }

    .card .creator{
        padding-top: 2%;
        text-align: right;
        font-style: italic;
    }
}
```

I also have very similar rules for the screens which are smaller, but those work correctly, as I see, on Chrome too.

How and why can this happen? I don't use any browser-specific rule as I know. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Are you using external URL for your foundation css stylesheet? (i.e. using foundation css / js hosted on some cdn of another domain name)

Comment: @KoalaYeung no, I downloaded it to reduce the loading time

Comment: Try to inspect your page with developer tools. See if you got any error message in developer console or network inspector.

Comment: @KoalaYeung I didn't get any error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using PHP with the the [Foundation CSS framework](https://get.foundation/sites/docs/), you should check out a package I wrote to address problems like this, [PHPFUI](http://phpfui.com/). It is a completely object oriented PHP solution to producing web pages with PHP. Basically you use patterns in the framework to solve problems like this.  I wrapped all the basic Foundation concepts in PHP, so you don't even need to figure out the HTML, which can get pretty gnarly. Of course you could write all that HTML by hand, but why bother? It is a solved problem. You don't write assembly language for the same reason, we have tools (languages, including markup), to abstract all this. Just write to the concept and let the tools do the work.

To do what you want, it would look like this:

```
namespace PHPFUI;

// Your autoloader here
include '../vendor/autoload.php';

$page = new Page();
$page->addStyleSheet('/css/styles.css');

$mainColumn = new \PHPFUI\Cell(12);
$mainColumn->addClass('main-column');

$gridX = new GridX();

$colA = new Cell(4);
$colA->add(new Image('https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/assets/img/rectangle-1.jpg'));
$gridX->add($colA);

$colB = new Cell(8);
$colB->add(new SubHeader('PHPFUI Rules!'));
$colB->add('This is some text next to the photo on the left');

$gridX->add($colB);

$page->add($gridX);

echo $page;
```

Pretty simple!